# Node-Red Tasmota Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.77.21:1883

Tags: node.js, mqtt, node-red, tasmota

I installed the Node-Red addon: "node-red-contrib-tasmota". When I try to use the "sensor" node, I get the error "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.77.21:1883".The ESP32 is connected locally to "http://192.168.77.21/" and uses port "1883"

[image: Sensor node]

[image: Tasmota-mqqt-broker]

I tried changing the ESP32 configs in Tasmota, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor will be connecting to a separate MQTT broker, it will not be running it's own MQTT broker on the device. You need to user the IP address of the broker, not the device.

Comment: Which MQTT broker can I use for free? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: The are so many open source brokers, but start with mosquitto